# Firebase path referring

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an android app and on my firebase database I have structure that look like this:

```
{
  "messages" : {
    "-Kn_ZygVCYa3NopeFqTM" : {
      "byUser" : "MzE7ySZywtZ20dK6UzayQ7juuUu2",
      "message" : "HeHeHaHa",
      "time_added" : 1498500294106,
      "used_count" : 0,
      "verified" : true
    },
    "message_2" : {
      "by_user" : "amdin",
      "message" : "Happy Diwali",
      "time_added" : 978451321,
      "used_count" : 5,
      "verified" : false
    },
    "message_3" : {
      "by_user" : "admin",
      "message" : "My best wished even if they are belated.",
      "time_added" : 456897986,
      "used_count" : 8,
      "verified" : false
    }
  }
}
```

I have `".read" = true;` permission on messages node. What I need is to filter the messages and get only those nodes which have verified flag as true. i.e. the above should return only `-Kn_ZygVCYa3NopeFqTM` message.

My code to get it for now is:

```
mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");
mMessagesReference.equalTo("verified", "true")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.e(TAG, dataSnapshot.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, databaseError.toString());
            }
        });
```

snapshot comes out to be null with this. The reason for this may be that messages has no child called verified, but whole problem is, that I don't have id's of messages beforehand. What should be the workaround to this?

Comment: `"verified"` is a boolean? How would it be equalTo a string?

Comment: there was no, equalTo(String,boolean) in documentation. So I thought thats how it may work

Comment: Are you using those backwards?  `equalTo(boolean value, String key)` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#equalTo(boolean, java.lang.String)

Comment: you need to use `orderByChild("verified").equalTo(true)` ...see answer below

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for bringing that to my notice. Do you think it should work now? verified is still no direct child?

Comment: Not really, but `orderByChild(key).equalTo(value)` is how the documentation says to deal with this scenario

Comment: Apparantly, `orderByChild(key).equalTo(value)` is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use something like:

```
mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");
mMessagesReference.orderByChild("verified").equalTo(true)....
```

Answer (score 1):

the `verified` is not a direct child for the `messages` node so the query will return null

```
 mMessagesReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Message  message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                        if (message.verified)
                          //code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.e(TAG, databaseError.toString());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I don't wish to do filtering on client, as in future data may become too heavy, say a million nodes.

Comment: you need to build an api for using the nodejs, or add a node `verified` and put the keys of verified node as children

Comment: I don't have any idea about making this api. Would I be able to host it on firebase itself? I believe making api would be a better approach for me provided i take care of security and scalability of data.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide me starting point to some good resource i could follow?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you need to add another node to your database named: `verifiedMessages`. This is the simples way and also helps you not to download the entire `messages` node, which would be a waste of bandwidth and will also be slow. In this new node, you need to add all messages ids as keys and the boolean as value. Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   ---- verifiedMessages
              |
              ---- "-Kn_ZygVCYa3NopeFqTM": true
              |
              ---- "-Kn_ZygVCYa3NopeFqTN": false
              |
              ---- "-Kn_ZygVCYa3NopeFqTQ": false
```

In this way you can set a listener on this new node to see which is `true` and which is `false`.

Hope it helps.